# Search for line containing [insert text] using grep

Tags: linux

I am trying to search for lines that only contain a set of brackets [....] with text inside the brackets

so lines that do not contain a set of close brackets will not be printed. How would i go about this using grep?

Comment: always looks simple...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this grep:

```
ps -ef | egrep  ' \[[^]]*\]'
```

Comment: When running ps -ef | egrep -x '\[[^]]*\]' i get no response from the terminal.

Comment: I've added the output above

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
grep -e '^\[.+\]$' file-name
```

Comment: I think that the bracket would have to be at the end of the line there

Comment: @ojblass `$` in regular expression means the end of the string.

Comment: Will this still work if i am grepping the output of a command through a pipe?

Comment: i forgot there are nine million types of regular expressions

Comment: @user2860658 It will work, for example `echo '[abc]' | grep ...`.